# Post NSUserDefaults changes between iOS Keyboard Extension and Containing app?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsnotifications, ios-keyboard-extension

I thought I have tried everything and read every possible articles in this forum.  But nothing seems to work.  Here is some code snippet and some settings:

On Extension side:

```
let thisDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.request.com")
thisDefaults?.setObject("Hello", forKey: "prevWord")
thisDefaults?.setObject("World", forKey: "word")
let success = thisDefaults?.Synchronize()
```

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ExtensionRequestChanges", object: nil)

On Containingg app side:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:                Selector("DidReceiveRequest:", name: "ExtensionRequestChanges", 
object: nil)

func DidReceiveRequest(notification: NSNotification) {
      // Read defaults
      let thisDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.request.com")
      let word = thisDefaults?.stringForKey("word")
      let prevWord = thisDefaults?.stringForKey("prevWord")
      ...
}
```

On the project settings:

```
. registered "group.request.com" app group to both the extension and containing app
. set "RequestOpenAccess" in NSExtensionAttributes to YES
```

But my DidReceiveRequest function never seemed to get called!  Why???

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`NSNotificationCenter` only works in the process it's running in. Your keyboard extension and container app are separate processes. To post interprocess notifications, you should investigate the `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter`API call, which returns a Core Foundation notification center that can post notifications between processes, or other forms of interprocess communication.

Comment: Thanks, @BenPious.  Do you have any example code on CFNotificationCenter (Darwin) in Swift, especially with AddObserver and PostNotification methods.  I am completely new in this area.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I figured out how to write the callback function for CFNotificationCenter in swift:

Comment: func callback(cf: CFNotificationCenter!,
        ump: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
        name: CFString!,
        up: UnsafePointer<Void>,
        userInfo: CFDictionary!) -> Void {
           print("Received a call for \(name)")
   }